# Can widgets.php invoke a js function?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, widget

Wordpress widgets are activated in a theme's `widgets.php` file.

The `Foo_Widget` example in the [Wordpress Widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) shows that widgets should call a `widget` function, an `update` function, and a `form` function, with the `widget` function containing the code that will be activated when widgets are displayed.

**Is there a way to have the `widget` function invoke a JavaScript function stored in a separate js file?**

Here's what I have tried with the `Foo_Widget` example linked above. The "fooey!" alert works fine, but instead of displaying a widget all that appears in the widget space is the word "undefined." Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**Header Text**

`<?php wp_enqueue_script( 'foo', get_template_directory_uri()."/js/foo.js" ); ?>`

**foo.js**

```
function foo( $args, $instance ) {

    alert("fooey!");

    document.write($args['before_widget']);

    if (!empty($instance['title'])) {
        document.write($args['before_title'].apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']).$args['after_title']);
    }

    document.write("Hello world!");
    document.write($args['after_widget']);
}
```

**Updated Widget Function**

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">foo(' . $args . ',' . $instance . ')' . ';</script>';
}
```

Comment: you cant use php in a js file